# Remove work from a io_context or using multiple io_context objects

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio, event-loop

Currently I'm trying to make it possible to remove work queued through `post` or `dispatch` to an `io_context`. The work is queued by a small amount of queuer groups for which the work shall be removeable all at once:

```
boost::asio::io_context context;

auto work = [] {
  // ...
};
boost::asio::post(context, std::move(work));

// ... now I want to remove the work
```

Is there such a functionality provided by the asio library?

Currently the application I'm working on, is using a thread pool which invokes `io_context::run()` from multiple threads.

My idea was that I could create multiple `io_context`s that are dispatched by the thread pool such that one `io_context` represents a group that could be removed through `io_context::stop()`. All `io_context`s would be held inside a single list which is then pooled for outstanding events.

However I believe that pooling or waiting for many `io_context`s could lead to performance issues.
Is there a different solution?

Comment: Have you checked the `${boost_root}/libs/asio/example/cpp11/executors/pipeline.cpp` ? I think you don't need more then one `io_context`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no mechanism for removing posted jobs from an `io_context`. Alternatively, you could modify your jobs to check if a 'cancel flag' is set before they run (untested):

```
// create a cancellation flag
const auto cancel = std::make_shared<std::atomic<bool> >();

auto work = [=] {

    // check to see if the flag has been set
    // if so, return without performing our task
    if(*cancel)
        return;

    // perform some task
};

// post our job
boost::asio::post(context, std::move(work));

...

// cancel all jobs checking this flag
*cancel = true;
```

Comment: Sadly, setting a cancel flag isn't enough here, since the work will contain references to code which is placed in a shared library that is unloaded after the work was removed / canceled and this willl lead to access violations. So it is really required to remove the work from the io_context as stated by the question.

Comment: @Naios - It doesn't matter if there are any invalid pointers captured in job lambda.
If job will just return immediately due to cancel, it will not access the invalid memory pointed by captured pointers.